# Creating a geodataframe from a list of LineStrings or routes

Tags: python, geopandas, linestring, geodataframe, osmnx

I have created a separate LineString for each origin-destination couples
of subdivisions and I did it manually cause when I use a for loop it creates a dataframe with 1 LineString from all lines...
Now I want to create a DataFrame containing all lineStrings with length of each one,
I have found this block of code online but it takes only 1 line at a time and when I pass the [routes lines variables] list,
I get the error

> ValueError: 1 columns passed, passed data had 16 columns

```
Gamle_routes_geom = gpd.GeoDataFrame([[Gamle_route_Grünerløkka_line,Gamle_route_Sagene_line,Gamle_route_Hanshaugen_line,Gamle_route_Frogner_line,
                                  Gamle_route_Ullern_line,Gamle_route_Vestre_line,Gamle_route_Nordre_Aker_line,
                                  Gamle_route_Bjerke_line,Gamle_route_Grorud_line,Gamle_route_Stovner_line,
                                  Gamle_route_Alna_line,Gamle_route_Østensjø_line,Gamle_route_nordstrand_line,
                                  Gamle_route_Søndre_line,Gamle_route_Sentrum_line,Gamle_route_Marka_line]],
                             geometry='geometry', crs=oslo_edges_proj.crs, columns=['geometry'])
```

Add a list of osmids associated with the route
had to change this to index as osmid was the column index of the object

```
Gamle_routes_geom.loc[0, 'osmids'] = str(list(gamle_routes_nodes.index.values))
```

Calculate the route length

```
Gamle_routes_geom['length_m'] = Gamle_routes_geom.length
```

Edit:
I will share the process:

1- pulled the data from osm using ox.graph_from_place()

2- got the nearest point for each centroid separately as follow:

```
Gamle_orig_node = ox.distance.nearest_nodes(oslo_graph_proj, Gamle_centroid.x, Gamle_centroid.y)
```

3- used nx.shortest_path() for each couple of orig-dest as follow:

```
Gamle_route_Grünerløkka = nx.shortest_path(G=oslo_graph_proj, source=Gamle_orig_node, target=Grünerløkka_orig_node, weight='length')
```

4- got the routes nodes from the main graph

```
for i in gamle_routes:
    gamle_routes_nodes = oslo_nodes_proj.loc[i]
```

5- got the nodes of each route from the nodes_graph

```
Gamle_route_Grünerløkka_nodes = oslo_nodes_proj.loc[Gamle_route_Grünerløkka]
```

6- got each route as a LineString

```
Gamle_route_Grünerløkka_line = LineString(list(Gamle_route_Grünerløkka_nodes.geometry.values))
```

7- now as the process done separately for each couple I have got separated lines and I want them in a dataframe a row for each couple to have the length of each route and plot on folium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your code as seen below:

```py
Gamle_routes_geom = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry':[Gamle_route_Grünerløkka_line,
                                                  Gamle_route_Sagene_line,
                                                  Gamle_route_Hanshaugen_line,
                                                  Gamle_route_Frogner_line,
                                                  Gamle_route_Ullern_line,
                                                  Gamle_route_Vestre_line,
                                                  Gamle_route_Nordre_Aker_line,
                                                  Gamle_route_Bjerke_line,
                                                  Gamle_route_Grorud_line,
                                                  Gamle_route_Stovner_line,
                                                  Gamle_route_Alna_line,
                                                  Gamle_route_Østensjø_line,
                                                  Gamle_route_nordstrand_line,
                                                  Gamle_route_Søndre_line,
                                                  Gamle_route_Sentrum_line,
                                                  Gamle_route_Marka_line]},
                                      geometry='geometry', 
                                      crs=oslo_edges_proj.crs)
```

Comment: WOW Thank you, this is worked :) and i got the geometry  values, what about the other 2 columns? length and osmid ?

Comment: Glad it helped! You can get the length using something like this: `Gamle_routes_geom['length']=Gamle_routes_geom.length`. The OSM IDs will be trickier. I believe that the route objects you have (i.e., the `Gemale_route_xyz_line` variables) are just simple shapely geometries and don't carry the associated information from the original OSM links. So you're going to have to modify the part of your code where you create these routes and find a way to extract those IDs and store them somewhere separately. Then you should add the OSM ID to the `Gamle_routes_geom` GeoDataFrame.

Comment: Also: if the solution provided worked, please consider accepting the answer and upvoting it too =)

Comment: I have selected it as an accepted answer, tho I can't upvote for the reason I need some reputation to do so :)

Comment: Great! Much appreciated =) And I hope the further clarification about the OSM IDs also helped!

Comment: yes, it did thank you, 
1 last thing, can I add a column with the dict geometry values as the destination column?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you want the column with the LineString geometries to be called `destination` instead of `geometry`? If so, yes, you can do that! Just change the code to `gpd.GeoDataFrame({'destination':[Gamle_route_x_line,...]},geometry='destination', crs=oslo_edges_proj.crs)`. All I did was change the key of the geometries in the dictionary to "destination" and point to the "destination" column as the one containing the geometries.

Comment: nope, I just wanted to add an orig and dest columns containing the 2 halves of the line name i,e: Gamle_route_Sagene_line
Gamle is Orig and Sagene is the destination ^^

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry, but no, there's no easy one-line way to do this given the way you've structured your data. Similarly to what I said about the OSM IDs, you will have to go back to the instant you **created** the  `Gamle_route_x_line` variables and store the origins and destinations separately and then add them to your GeoDataFrame after the fact.

Comment: It is clear now Thank you so much for your time

Comment: I believe an easier approach would be to store all of this info at once as you create each individual route. For example, you can create a list of dictionaries as follows: `master_results = [{'origin':'Gamle','destination':'Sagene','geometry':Gamle_route_Sagene_line,'length':Gamle_route_Sagene_line.length,'OSM IDs':['id1','id2','id3']},{...},{...},...,{...}]`. Then, you can make a GeoDataFrame from it just adding `master_results_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(master_results, crs=geometry='destination', crs=oslo_edges_proj.crs)`.

Comment: Happy to help =)

Comment: Thank you, and regarding the master dictionary, I will see if I can replace it with the current one
and what is the logic behind 2 crs?

Comment: Ah, sorry, that was a typo! the command should be `gpd.GeoDataFrame(master_results, geometry='destination', crs=oslo_edges_proj.crs)`.